# What's the purpose of the full wave diode bridge in this DC-DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, rectifier

In the following power supply circuit, there is a full wave diode bridge (full wave rectifier?) after the DC Input. I can see how we need a full wave rectifier after an AC input, but why after a DC input? Is it to smooth out power signal?

Thanks

[image]

[Circuitlib Schematic](http://www.circuitlib.com/images/projects/power_supply/5V_LM2575_sch.pdf)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks to me like it's purely for the convenience (and maybe safety) of the user. It allows you to connect the input using any polarity you choose rather forcing a specific polarity on you.

Comment: Ah, makes a lot of sense!

Comment: +1 Yup, we switched polarity on wall warts, and went from a series protection diode to a bridge for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

Majenko is correct; the bridge is there so the end user can ignore polarity when applying DC voltage to the circuit.

Another option is to use a single diode in series. This will protect the circuit from accidental miss wiring but the circuit will not be functional unlike the full bridge solution.

Comment: I like that you expanded on the alternative/usual approach when you do not do the bridge method, or a P-FET (for higher power, same result as a single diode)